# Get html result from web page

Tags: c#, .net

I am planning create a movil application (for fun) that should use the result from this web page (http://consultawebvehiculos.carabineros.cl/index.php). is there any ways to create a instance of a browser in my Net code and read this result and publish it using a web service..
something like:

```
var IE= new broswer("http://consultawebvehiculos.carabineros.cl/index.php");
var result=IE.FindElementByID("txtIdentityCar").WriteText(YourIdentityCar);
publicToWebSerivce(result);
```

Update:
Using Fiddler i can see that http post is somthing like that:

```
POST http://consultawebvehiculos.carabineros.cl/index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: consultawebvehiculos.carabineros.cl
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 61
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://consultawebvehiculos.carabineros.cl
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)      Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://consultawebvehiculos.carabineros.cl/index.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

accion=buscar&txtLetras=CL&txtNumeros1=sk&txtNumeros2=12&vin=
```

May be i need some .Net class like webclient in order connect with the php page...no sure.

UPDATE: I finally i found the solution using Fiddler to know the total parameters and I've used the code from http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPOSTsAndHTTPGETsWithWebClientAndCAndFakingAPostBack.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your are just interested in scraping the page, I suggest using [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

If you also want to display the page, then you could use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control.

Comment: What i would like to do with the page is:
1) connect with the php page.
2) add input to the page. 
3) send this information using http post.
4) wait for the response and check the html.

Answer (score 0):

We've been using http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ for similair tasks. It allows you to send requests, receive response/status code/etc.

(it's a Java lib, so you could either google for a .Net port or use a converter to convert Java assembly into .Net assembly - see http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/30/using-htmlunit-on-net-for-headless-browser-automation/ for guidance. We've used the convertion approach).